# Diagram uses for structural programming?

Tags: diagram

Currently I'm writing a theses for software project, Which uses structural programming techniques. DFD,Context diagrams may helps to depict the software, is there any other diagrams could help to describe the software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a programming related question but **Structure Charts** are probably your best bet.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_chart

This may also be of interest:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_structured_programming

Comment: Thanks , I have seen many same related post here, that's why I have submit such a question. Currently I'm writing a theses for a software project.

Comment: Ahhh, ok.  You should edit the question to specify (just so people don't quickly down vote your question).

Comment: I can't ask any more questions here. :-(